# Changing position of Gridview Paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, paging

I want to change the position of default (bottom of grid) asp:gridview paging to right side of gridview. Is it possible?

if not please suggest if i can keep two buttons outside gridview to change the page index of gridview.

Comment: Did you do any google [search](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=FAYfU-LnL8j9ygOB6YHgDg#q=pager+location+of+gridview)?? or [GridView Custom Paging](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25835/GridView-Custom-Paging-with-PageSize-Change-Dropdo)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PagerSettings.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pagersettings.position%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to change the position. You can set `Bottom`, `Top` and `TopAndBottom`

You can alight left or right using [`PagerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagerstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
```

Comment: it has only three options Top, Bottom & TopBottom; I want to keep it on right side of gridview

Comment: You can use PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign, check my updated answer.

Comment: thanks @Adil but i want to show pager vertically right side. PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" keeps the paging horizontally right